# raspi ubuntu 20 - apt-get update problem - linux firmware / linux-raspi / linux-image-raspi

Tags: boot-issues, kernel, apt, update, firmware

Hy

my raspi has this fstab:

```
UUID=7d298733-8450-4adb-b654-6de49954db5c       /        btrfs          defaults        0 0
UUID=AD5E-0725       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Then the disc UUID=AD5E-0725 /boot/firmware got corrupt and i restored the contents of it from a backup about a year old. The system booted up normally.

But as soon as the first kernel update was made it did not boot. Took me a while to figure out why, but this is the problem.

```
r@r-pi:~$ sudo dpkg -C
[sudo] password for rodney: 
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
linux-image-raspi    Raspberry Pi Linux kernel image
linux-raspi          Complete Raspberry Pi Linux kernel and headers

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
linux-firmware       Firmware for Linux kernel drivers

r@r-pi:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-firmware:armhf
```

So the problem is that apt-get has somewhere in its database that the last versions of these packages were around kernel version 4.x.y-zzzz-raspi. I manually copied /boot and /boot/firmware folder so the device boots with kernel 5.4.0-1015-raspi, but as soon as it tries to update to 5.4.0-1030-raspi the following errors occurs:

```
flash-kernel: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1015-raspi
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_QvTD7G/lib/modules/5.4.0-1015-raspi/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
find: ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_QvTD7G/lib/modules/5.4.0-1015-raspi/kernel’: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_QvTD7G/lib/modules/5.4.0-1015-raspi: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_QvTD7G/lib/modules/5.4.0-1015-raspi: No such file or directory
Using DTB: bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.0-1015-raspi /lib/firmware/5.4.0-1015-raspi/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-1015-raspi/./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-raspi:
linux-image-raspi depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-raspi (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up initramfs-tools-bin (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-raspi:
linux-raspi depends on linux-image-raspi (= 5.4.0.1030.65); however:
  Package linux-image-raspi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-raspi (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up initramfs-tools-core (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
```

Any ideas how to fix this, so that i can once more do regular updates?

btw this is the list of commands i tried to fix this:

```
  966  sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
  967  sudo apt install linux-firmware

  999  sudo apt-get full-upgrade
 1001  sudo apt remove linux-firmware linux-image-raspi linux-raspi
 1002  sudo apt-get install  linux-firmware linux-image-raspi linux-raspi
```